# SwiftUI TextEditor View content is hidden behind Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, navigationbar, swiftui-texteditor

I'm working on a SwiftUI View with a `NavigationBar`. The view is very simple, it's a full-page `TextEditor`:

```swift
struct NotesEditingScreen: View {
    
    @State var text: String
    
    var body: some View {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .navigationBarTitle("Editing")
    }
}
```

The issue I'm seeing, is that when landing on this screen (via a `NavigationLink`) the top of the `TextEditor` is covered up by Navigation Bar:

[image: gif demonstrating issue]

My desired behavior is that the `TextEditor` content appears beneath the Navigation Bar, like it appears after you manually scroll to the top to reveal the text.

Is there a solution/workaround to this issue? I was hoping for either some offset, a setting on NavigationBar, or some programmatic scroll behavior that could be done `onAppear`. Any suggestions welcome.

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's an unexpected behavior.

You can try this:

```swift
GeometryReader { geo in
    ScrollView {
        TextEditor(text: $text)
            .frame(height: geo.size.height)
    }
}
```